# RadEditor Control sends tech jargon with emails

Tags: telerik

I am using a RadEditor control in ASP.NET web application. It is mainly being used for email body. Users usually copy and paste the content from MS Word to this control and send the email through this application. Users are using Chrome browser from Chrome Book. But users complained of an issue now. When the users send the email, recipients are receiving some tech jargon like below along with the email content.

```
<qowt-page named-flow="FLOW-1" style="display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-box-align: stretch; -webkit-box-pack: justify; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; box-shadow: #d1d1d1 0px 0px 0px 1px, #cccccc 0px 0px 4px 1px; overflow: hidden; margin: auto auto 5mm; position: relative; color: #000000; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; width: 595.3pt; height: 841.9pt; cursor: text !important;">
```

I have no idea what is this junk they are receiving. I tried to simulate this issue in IE and Google Chrome browsers in Windows machines but could not simulate it. Only users who are using Google Chrome in Chrome book are having this issue. Email is sent through Chrome book.

I have already tried the following code with no result. txtContent is RadControl here.

```
txtContent.StripFormattingOptions = EditorStripFormattingOptions.MSWordNoMargins | EditorStripFormattingOptions.ConvertWordLists;

txtContent.DisableFilter(Telerik.Web.UI.EditorFilters.ConvertToXhtml);
```

I tried enabling and disabling Brotli-Content encoding in Chrome browser but could not simulate it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please do not add begging messages into your title to hurry answers. Helpers may still assist here, but an answer is not guaranteed, since volunteers cannot be placed under any sort of obligation. If your need for help is genuinely urgent, you may wish to consider other avenues for support.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `txtContent.Content` to get the send the email without the jargon to be sent in the email body.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to strip the Word formatting through the StripFormattingOptions property in these online resources:

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/editor/managing-content/pasting-content/clean-ms-word-formatting

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/editor/managing-content/pasting-content/clean-ms-word-formatting-on-page-load-and-on-submit

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/cleaningwordformatting/defaultcs.aspx